# I can't install pinta

Tags: pinta

Every time I try to install from the software center I get this package dependencies error:

[image: package dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with terminal

To open terminal: Ctrl + alt + t

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pinta
```

Comment: When I try that I get this

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/moonlight-team/pinta/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/calibre2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/calibre2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/calibre2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 0):

### PPA conflict

I had a similar issue in my Desktop. I was using another program that was not from the official repository and caused a conflict. In my case it was `Emby Server`.

Since I stopped using `Emby`, I **removed all the dependencies*** that conflicted and then was able to install `pinta` from the regular repositories.

***** Be careful not to uninstall a program you use along with this dependencies.

I was unable to find a solution where I could keep them both.

### Detect Culprit

To know what software is causing the conflict run:

> sudo apt-get -s remove libmono-libcairo2.0-cil

The output will list all the programs that will be uninstall because they depend on this library. One of this programs is the culprit.

### Try something else:

If none of these works try to look up this link about unmet dependencies: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: When I tried it I got this: gerry@gerry-550P5C-550P7C:~$ sudo apt-get -s remove libmono-libcairo2.0-cil
[sudo] password for gerry: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmono-libcairo2.0-cil
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmono-libcairo2.0-cil'
gerry@gerry-550P5C-550P7C:~$

Comment: Will get back to you tomorrow. But try to look up this link about unmet dependencies: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa